# Where should Relay.Route objects live?

Tags: relayjs

In Relay,

What I understood so far is that each time you render a component (via Relay.Renderer) with a new Relay.Route, it's going to re-fetch again the data. So if you forceUpdate() your component at 10 fps, and if you do a `new UserRoute({ userId })` **from inside render()** that you pass to `queryConfig`, it's going to fetch again the data, and even if the actual userId didn't even changed. is this correct? Is that a way to force refresh the data too?

Which leads to my question: what is the good practice on where to put the Relay.Route objects?

So far, I was putting them in a React state, on my Screen/Page component.
For instance let's say `/user/123`.
Then, in `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle, if I receive new id (like I move to `/user/666`) I'm doing a `setState({ userRoute: new UserRoute({ userId }) })`

Thanks!